# Wrong class type in objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a parent class and a child class.  GameObjectBase (parent) GameObjectPlayer(child).  When I override a method in Child class and call it using

```
[myPlayerClass showNextFrame]
```

It is calling the parent class one.  It turns out in the debugger, I see the myPlayerClass was indeed class type GameObjectBase (which is the parent class)  How come?

GameObjectBase.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"

@class GameLayer;

@interface GameObjectBase : NSObject
{
/*    CCSprite *gameObjectSprite;    // Sprite representing this game object
    GameLayer *parentGameLayer; */  // Reference of the game layer this object
    // belongs to
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) CCSprite *gameObjectSprite;
@property (nonatomic, assign) GameLayer *parentGameLayer; 

// Class method.  Autorelease
+ (id) initWithGameLayer:(GameLayer *) gamelayer
           imageFileName:(NSString *) fileName;


// "Virtual methods" that the derived class should implement.
// If not implemented, this method will be called and Assert game
- (void) update: (ccTime) dt;
- (void) showNextFrame;

@end
```

GameObjectPlayer.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GameObjectBase.h"
@interface GameObjectPlayer : GameObjectBase
{
    int direction;
}

@property (nonatomic) int direction;
@end
```

GameLayer.h

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "GameObjectPlayer.h"

@interface GameLayer : CCLayer
{

}

// returns a CCScene that contains the GameLayer as the only child
+(CCScene *) scene;

@property (nonatomic, strong) GameObjectPlayer *player;
@end
```

When I call examine in debugger what type "temp" is in this function inside GameLayer class, it's giving parent class GameObjectBase instead of subclass GameObjectPlayer

```
- (void) update:(ccTime) dt
{
    GameObjectPlayer *temp = _player;

    [temp showNextFrame];

}
```

Comment: How are you setting value for player? Couldnt see the code for that in the above example. Since temp = equated to player, I assume that the issue is with the code where you are creating player.

Comment: How do you create the player object?

Answer (score 0):

You are just assigning the value. Please allocate it & then assign it.

Hope it resolves your issue.